# Android: How to add Public Transport layer to Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

My Android application uses Google Maps API v2 to show train stations. How can I enable the Public Transport layer (in my code) so that I can show train/railway lines?

I do not want any transit data, just the map layer that shows train/railway lines (e.g. the London Underground coloured train lines).

See this link for what I want:
[Google Maps Public Transport Layer](http://www.blendor.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/picture-4-297x300.png)

Comment: The layers you see in the Google Maps application are part of the **application**, not the **API**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start with getting the data.

After you have all the latitudes, longitudes, colors and whatever else you need (either hardcoded in APK or retrieved from webservice), use Polyline to draw everything.

You can't simply turn on such layers in your app.

Comment: Thanks MaciejGórski. Nicopico, that is what I was after, exactly what the Google Maps application does with the layer.

Will I have to draw each of the train lines manually (or with existing data) with PolyLines?

Comment: there is no builtin functionality for Android?